# Java RESTful web service error: Cannot access WADL

Tags: java, rest, web-services, web-applications, netbeans-8

I've created a Java RESTful web service using NetBeans 8.0 and GlassFish server 4.0, using my database(local). When I click the "Test RESTful web services" my default web browser opens with an alert saying:

> Cannot access WADL: Please restart your RESTful application, and
>   refresh this page.

Note: Using the default sample database everything works fine.

---

**Update**: I'm following this tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

Comment: Are you following an online tutorial to do this? If so, please update your question with a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the version of jdk and tomcat.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem as the question, tried your solution

Changed from GlassFish to Tomcat, didn't work, change jdk, still get the same error, any other tip?

Answer (score -1):

in netbeans in your source package where the restful .java file is click on that file and one of the lines of code will have an error lightbulb saying that restfull is not configured properly click on that and everything will be fixed.